# Synchronizing copied repository with GIT repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I have copied repository from my team member and I want to synchronize with GIT repository. 
Please keep in mind that I am new to GIT and I only have URLs of the repository where I need to synchronize. I need help to connect my repository with GIT repository. I have not imported any repository and I have just copied that. I will be able to push or pull or merge etc. only if my project is synchronized with remote repository. Please let me know that how can I synchronize. Thanks

Comment: I have googled... I am sure that this is forum to answer the problems and help those who need rather than discouraging new ones.

Comment: what do you mean by copy? did you copy the sources? did you copy the `.git` folder? did you clone it?

Comment: i just copied the project folders and not the .git folder..no i did not clone

Comment: Do you want to use the project in Eclipse (through EGit team provider)? Do you plan to synchronize directly with your team member or only with the main repo that he cloned from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your question whether you are trying to simply keep two copies of the same repository synchronized or something else.

If it's the first, then what you want to do it a `git clone`. Your changes should be `git commit`, to get remote changes you should `git pull` and to push your changes to your co-worker's repository, you should `git push`.

Depending on your operating system, there are different front-ends for Git. I gave you the command-line version. I saw you tagged your questions with the `eclipse` tag, which suggests you are trying to do this inside Eclipse. In that case, you might find EGit useful. See the [EGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) here.

If all this sounds too complex for you, you should first Read The Manual - that is, check out the [Getting Started](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) chapter of the Git Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had to go in team-> share projects. then "create a new repository location" and paste the url of git repository. then team->share project-> git and add the repository. Now my copied repository is linked/connected with my git repository and I am able to synchronize my repository.